# Problem installing Rcmdr on 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I have R installed, but I can't install Rcmdr, always getting answer "Package Rcmdr not available"

Comment: Are you looking for `r-cran-rcmdr` perhaps? `apt-cache search rcmdr`

Answer (score 0):

Installing of `r-cran-rcmdr` [from official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/r-cran-rcmdr) will not be enough.
It is outdated so is not fully-functional.
It wants to use the `sem` package, which currently exists [only for R (≥ 3.5.0)](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/sem/index.html).

So you have to remove the `r-cran-rcmdr` package by

```
sudo apt-get remove r-cran-rcmdr
```

Then add [newer repository](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) for R 4.0 by commands below:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran40/"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Then install the R packages with build dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

Finally install R commander in `R` session

```
install.packages('Rcmdr')
```

as user package.

To run R commander use command below:

```sh
R_DEFAULT_PACKAGES=Rcmdr R
```

and confirm installation of remaining needed R packages.